# How do I get this function to run without clicking the location of the nearest marker found on my project using Google Maps API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have slightly modified the following demo here http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_closestPlacesDirections.html

Here is a little demo I have setup so far just so everyone can see how far I am... http://www.redwoodstravel.co.uk/test/index.html

Using this demo I have an array of multiple markers, each of these locations is always the starting pointing of the driving route. I have a waypoint (start variable) and the end point (end variable) is always the end point.

The closest marker to the start variable will be found fine, whatever I change this variable to it will look through the array of markers and get me the closest.

The closest marker is visible on the map and you can see underneath the map "Plymouth" should be the closest in my example to "Tavistock" the start variable.

Upon clicking on the Plymouth link the route will be calculated and get me the mileage and journey in minutes.

I'm guessing this is the piece of code that needs work on...

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) { return function()        
{
     getDirections(customerMarker.getPosition(),locations[i][3],endpoint);         
}      
})
(marker, i));
```

I have tried changing the event listener to "map, 'tilesloaded'" but on the page loading it just goes a bit crazy and looks at a couple routes before deciding on the wrong start point.

I have also had a look at dom listeners but still having a similar problem.

Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction, feel free to view the source on my demo!

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking how to trigger a 'click' event on the single result from the search for the closest marker?

Comment: @geocodezip no, just to find the nearest marker to the start point (which it does), and get the directions without the above click event. Ideally to get the directions on page load correctly.